# Convertir de manera correcta la fecha

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-forms, datetime

**Buenas, tengo esta consulta en SQL:

```
SELECT TOP(1) CONVERT(DATE, FechaDesde) AS FechaDesde, CONVERT(DATE, FechaHasta) AS FechaHasta, MES, ANO 
FROM periodos 
WHERE IdProcesoAdmin=2 
AND FechaHasta IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY IdPeriodo DESC
```

Que me imprime la fecha corta:

```
25/11/2020
```

Ahora, quiero llevarlo a C# y lo hago así:

```
    public List<Fechas> fechasParaLabel()
    {
        List<Fechas> lista = new List<Fechas>();
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(BD))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            string consulta = "SELECT TOP(1) CONVERT(CHAR(10), FechaDesde, 103) AS FechaDesde, CONVERT(CHAR(10), FechaHasta, 103) AS FechaHasta, MES, ANO " +
                              "FROM periodos " +
                              "WHERE IdProcesoAdmin=2 " +
                              "AND FechaHasta IS NOT NULL " +
                              "ORDER BY IdPeriodo DESC";
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(consulta, sqlConnection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Fechas fechas = new Fechas();
                            fechas.desde = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["FechaDesde"]?.ToString());
                            fechas.hasta = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["FechaHasta"]?.ToString());
                            fechas.MES = dr["MES"]?.ToString();
                            fechas.ANO = dr["ANO"]?.ToString();
                            lista.Add(fechas);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw ex;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

Pero, esto me imprime la fecha más la hora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Leí que hay que usar el `ToShortDateString()` pero me dice que la conversión implícita no se puede realizar. ¿Cómo se hace de manera correcta?

Clase:

```
class Fechas
    {
        public DateTime desde { get; set; }
        public DateTime hasta { get; set; }
        public string MES { get; set; }
        public string ANO { get; set; }

        public Fechas(DateTime desde, DateTime hasta, string mES, string aNO)
        {
            this.desde = desde;
            this.hasta = hasta;
            MES = mES;
            ANO = aNO;
        }

        public Fechas() { }
    }
```

Comment: en donde te imprime la fecha y hora?

Comment: Mala mía, no agregué qyue estoy trabajando con window-form

Comment: Traelo como datetime desde la consulta sql, no es necesario un casteo, el casteo se lo harías desde c#

Comment: estas convirtiendo lo que viene de la base de datos a datetime...datetime incluye la hora... esta pregunta deberia tener la clase que tiene la pregunta anterior, ya que veo que no leiste del todo lo que te marque como detalles en ella...

Comment: Pues, a tu respuesta de la pregunta anterior le tuve que añadir el `ToString()` porque traía error de conversión. @gbianchi

Comment: Pero, gracias a eso he descubierto la solución. Gracias

Comment: si le agregaste el tostring y luego es un datetime en la clase, entonces el problema esta en otro lado, porque lo esta convirtiendo a datetime de vuelta al pasarlo a la clase...

Comment: Claro, pero al cambiar `lblDesde.Text = ((Fechas)lista.ElementAt(0)).desde;` eso por esto: `lblDesde.Text = ((Fechas)lista.ElementAt(0)).desde.ToShortDateString();` me muestra la fecha corta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar con algo como esto

```
fechas.desde = DateTime.Parse(FechaDesde).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                            
fechas.hasta = DateTime.Parse(FechaHasta).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

public Fechas(DateTime desde, DateTime hasta, string mES, string aNO)
        {
            this.desde =  DateTime.Parse(desde).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            this.hasta = DateTime.Parse(hasta).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");;
            MES = mES;
            ANO = aNO;
        }
```

espero te sirva

Comment: Gracias, es una forma diferente de hacerlo :)